# how to run response.redirect on for loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, response.redirect

I Have process that should run atau go to url , but it should run on for loop :

```
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            idCustomer = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("House").ToString()
            amt = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("OPR_BALANCE").ToString()
            lang = "0"
            aid = "000000"
            Dim result As String = "http://soap.Services.com:2121/WS.aspx/?c=1&id=" + idCustomer + "&lang=" + lang + ""
            Response.Redirect(result)

Next
```

but right now, based on my code, redirect to the url and , the progress is automaticly stop because its redirected.

is it possible to run process by redirectt to URL on for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting inside a loop wont work. You need to call the service in other way.
Try using `DownloadString` method of `WebClient`. Extract `result` by this:

```
Dim client As New WebClient()
Dim result As String = client.DownloadString("http://soap.Services.com:2121/WS.aspx/?c=1&id=" + idCustomer + "&lang=" + lang )
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you call the Redirect you are done.... you can't redirect to mutiple pages....its illogical.....

Look this discussion : [Redirect loop](http://forums.asp.net/t/1413649.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do it with using response.redirect(). instead, you can use clientside code(JS) to do this logic. do your logic in JS and open up new pages with JS.

you can use jquery to call a webmethod. that webmethod can do the database stuff for you and return the data as json object. then you can do your logic in jquery to open new pages

I hope this helps